# How to handle calling a python notification script multiple times?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to write a script to automate my backups under linux and I would like to have some kind of system tray notification (KDE) that a backup is running.

after reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301267/notification-progress-in-tray-from-command-line#387673) other SE post and doing some research, I cannot seem to find a DBUS library for bash, so instead I am thinking of tweaking the python script from his answer and making it into an addon for my main backup script by having my bash backup script repeatedly call the python notification script to create, update, and remove the notification when the backup is done.

However, i'm not quite sure how to implement this on the python side since if I were to just call `python3 notify.py argument1 argument2` from bash, it would create a new instance of the python script every time.

Essentially, here's what i'm trying to do in my bash script:

```
#awesome backup script
./notification.py startbackup #this creates a new instance of the python script and sets up the KDE progress bar, possibly returning some kind of ID that is reused later?

#do backup things here.....

#periodically
./notification.py updateProgress 10%
./notification.py updateProgress 20%
#etc...

#finish the backup...

./notification.py endbackup #set the progressbar to complete and do cleanup
```

Since I havent done anything like this before and am not sure what to search for, I am wondering **How I would go about implementing something like this in the python/bash setup I have now?**

i.e. if i were to make a bash variable to store an instance ID that was returned from the first call to the python script and pass it back on each subsequent call, how would i have to write my python script in order to handle this and act on the same notification created originally, rather than creating new ones?

Answer (score 1):

Either keep the process running and send commands through a pipe or use a file to store the instance ID.

Comment: So i would use something like this? https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind this might be more elegant but using a file is much simpler.

Comment: Why would i need to use a file to store the ID? i was imagining i could just store it in a bash variable and reuse it on every subsequent call. My question is, how would that be implemented in python if it is indeed the best solution?

Comment: You are correct, you can pass the ID to the script on the command line. This is simper than what I suggested.

Comment: But how would i implement the python end of that? how would the python script keep track of the instances and know how to modify the existing one?

Comment: This question is too broad to answer. You originally asked about persistency between different instances of the script, which can be achieved through the bash script side of the setup. If you have another specific qustion, you can edit this question or open a new one.

Comment: I am confident that i will be able to get bash and python to communicate. My question was asking how to write a python script such that it multiple calls to it dont create multiple instances and instead update the first instance. I have never done this in python before and im wondering how to make python do what i want